# react js with mysql, how to use select with args?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm studying react js with nodejs using mysql. there are so many examples I saw only using no args select. but I want to use select with some args. I wrote my code. but in req.body, there is no args I set. what should I fix?

*react*

```
  callApi=async()=>{
    let va=1

    const response = await fetch('/api/customers',{
      method:'GET',
      body:JSON.stringify(va)
    });
    const body = await response.json();
    return body;
  }
```

*node*

```
app.get('/api/customers',(req,res)=>{
    let sql = "select * from customer where id=?";
    params=[req.body.va]; //no recommand, so I got error.

    connection.query(
        sql,params,
        (err,rows,fields)=>{
            res.send(rows);
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In React code, try passing body as object `body:JSON.stringify({"va":va})`
Then in node code, you can access the va variable -

```
 const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
 const params = [body.va];
```

Also, you need to change http verb to POST instead of GET for passing request data.

Comment: I followed, but got error."this.state.customer.map is not a function"